# Jira Software - System health gadget

Tags: jira, agile, jira-plugin, sprint

We've taken `Jira` software for agile project management. Not seeing the 'Sprint Helath Gadget'. Do we need to take something else to get this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have 50 pts, to comment on your question.

Assuming you're running JIRA Software as you stated (not plain JIRA), is the dashboard loading all of the widgets?  Sometimes, it says "trying to load more widgets" or whatever.  I have to close out the dashboard widget modal and reopen.

There it lets me select "Load All" and then it loads under the JIRA Category.  It should always be there by default given it's a local JIRA Software gadget.

You should see the JIRA category containing 47 different widgets, and if you type sprint in the search, there should be 4 results.  If not, your JIRA Software license is not fully active or working OR your install isn't working properly and you'll need to ping JIRA support.  I've had to get them to fix my instance a few times for various reasons.

Hope this gets you going.